# Misunderstanding creating r function

Tags: database, r, function, unique

I am trying to create a function with a command line that was working. I was creating an identifier for a dataset that looks like this

```
Nom Var1  Var2
N1    v11   v12
N2     .     .
N2     .     .
N3    V32   V32
```

My command was: `transform(df$Nom, id=match(df$Nom, unique(df$Nom)))` and works just fine. 
However, if I write a function like ht following one; I get the error: *"unique applies only to vectors"*

```
 createid<-function(var){
   x<- transform(var, id=match(var, unique(var)))
   ids<-paste0("id_",x[,2])
   return(ids)
 }
df$id<-createid(df$Nom)
```

Similarly, if Y write the following function, I get the error *Error in d$var : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable*

```
 createid<-function(d,var){
    x<- transform(d$var, id=match(d$var, unique(d$var)))
    ids<-paste0("id_",x[,2])
    return(ids)
  }
 df$id<-createid(d,Nom)
```

I think there is something I am not understanding in the way you should write functions in R, especially when you call variables inside a data frame. Can someone help me with this? 
Thank you

Comment: Could you also include the creation of df? Like df <- data.frame( sample data )

Comment: Usually the `transform` first argument is `data` itself, instead of a vector. ie. `transform(df, id=match(Nom, unique(Nom)))[-(2:3)]`

Comment: `d$var` will not work in a function if you pass `d` and `var` arguments separately. Use `d[['var']]` instead. That's why you get a `Error in d$var : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` error

Comment: @LyzandeR Please post as a solution

Comment: @akrun Thanks Akrun :). It only solves half of his problem, the other half is solved by you haha. That's why I didn't post.

Comment: @LyzandeR It's okay but the main part is your contribution, so you can post it.

Comment: @akrun Thanks Akrun. I really think that your part was the main part of the solution :). I would be more happy if you posted the answer and included mine rather than the opposite. Otherwise, it feels like I 'm stealing your answer :P

Comment: @akrun there should be combined answers as an option.

Comment: Post the solution and credit whoever helped you solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without using `transform`.   As @LyzandeR mentioned in the comments, it is better to use `d[[var]]` instead of `d$var`.

```
createid <- function(d, var){
            d$id <- match(d[[var]], unique(d[[var]]))
             d }
createid(df, 'Nom')
#   Nom Var1 Var2 id
#1  N1  v11  v12  1
#2  N2    .    .  2
#3  N2    .    .  2
#4  N3  V32  V32  3
```

Or if you really wanted to use `$`, then you could use `eval(parse(`, but this route is not recommended and not that simple.

```
   createid1 <- function(d, var){
                 m1 <- match.call()
                 e1 <- eval(parse(text=paste0(deparse(m1$d),'$',m1$var)))
                 d$id <- match(e1, unique(e1))
                 d}

   createid1(df, 'Nom')
   #  Nom Var1 Var2 id
   #1  N1  v11  v12  1
   #2  N2    .    .  2
   #3  N2    .    .  2
   #4  N3  V32  V32  3
```

Or instead of `eval(parse`

```
  createid2 <- function(d, var){
    args <- as.list(match.call())
    e1 <- eval(args$var, d)
    d$id <- match(e1, unique(e1))
    d
   }

 createid2(df, Nom)
 #  Nom Var1 Var2 id
 #1  N1  v11  v12  1
 #2  N2    .    .  2
 #3  N2    .    .  2
 #4  N3  V32  V32  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work just fine. As a general rule, is it always impossible to use `df$var` inside a function specified with the arguments `(df,var)`? What is the difference inside a function between `df[['var']]` and `df$var`?

Comment: Great answer Akrun. Thanks for posting. To answer Doon's question, you can never use df$var with separate `df, var arguments`. You can find out about the differences between `df$var` and `df[['var']]` type `help['$']` on your console.

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR.  Doon_Bogan: I would say, it is better to use `[[` as it is hazzle free and the differences are clearly mentioned here `?'['`.  But if you want to use `$`, you can by going through the `eval(parse(` route which is not that recommended.  I can update the post with that function.

Comment: @akrun, Oh I don't particularly want the `$` operator. I was just curious about why it would work in certain cases and not on others. Thanks for asking!